# Pure virtual function call from Java app?

Tags: java, virtual-functions

I have a Java application deployed on thousands of PC's and two or three of them periodically get an error message titled "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library" with the text "Runtime Error! R6025 -pure virtual function call."

The cause of the error itself is well documented on the internet, but the problem is that I'm not directly working with any C++ objects.  The Java process does have some JNI code, written in plain old non-object oriented C.  As I understand the error, it would require creating or destroying some abstract objects to cause it, and the C code doesn't do anything like that.  In addition, non of the JNI code is executing at the time this error pops up.

Anybody have any ideas about what could cause this, or at least how to get some sort of stack trace about what the program is trying to do when this happens?

Comment: does the jvm generate a .hserrorlog ?  If so, can you attach the output ?

Answer (score 1):

> thousands of PC's and two or three of them

This statement highly suggests that they have either a faulty JRE or a Visual ++ Runtime Library installation. The use of JNI may have confused you and made you believe that the problem is on your end, but it high probably is not.

Comment: I get this frequently when closing the Minecraft launcher, and I clean install Java whenever there's a new version.